# Php stream_socket_client - Only one packet is sent

Tags: php, sockets

I have got a client server application using TLS and C# and I have a requirement to make an extension with PHP.

I am able to establish a connection and receive data once, after that, the server doesn't receive anything else and the php script reaches the end.

My PHP code is as follow:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("tls://localhost:1776", $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    die("Unable to connect: $errstr ($errno)");
}



fwrite($fp, "Test1");
fwrite($fp, "Test2");

fclose($fp);
echo "DONE!";
```

I have attempted several approaches but the second fwrite never reaches the server no matter what. I am 100% sure the server is not the problem as the code is exactly the same for the C# client and that one works flawless.

Could anyone give me any tips on how to overcome this?

Thanks for reading and best regards.

Comment: How do you check the received data?

Comment: Maybe you can try to read server response? `while(!feof($fp)) echo fgets($fp, 1024);`

Comment: I am checking my received data, I just removed the code from the sample to be more clear.